# greater than a certain number sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date, select, count

I need to make an sql query that will show the following:

'Total number of active accounts that are more than 90 days old as of the current date'

The date is coming from an sql query which is this:

```
select date from currentdatetable
```

Now my query is to count all active accounts that come from the accountstable so my query goes like this:

```
select count(*) from accountstable
```

My problem is how do I state that the date from the accountstable is greater than 90 days old than the date of the currentdatetable?

My current code:

```
select count(*) from accountstable at where at.date > (select date from currentdatetable)
```

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server 2005

Comment: Just curious, why do you have a table with the current date? And is there only one record in it?

Comment: it is not a system date. the dates vary depending on which database it is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*) from accountstable at where at.date > (select dateadd(day, -90,date) from currentdatetable)
```

Comment: Your parameters are in the wrong order for DATEADD - count(*) from accountstable at where at.date < (select DATEADD(day, -90, date) from currentdatetable)

Comment: sorry, have now fixed

Comment: hi andy, why is yours <? it should be > right? since we're looking for accounts greater than the date?

Comment: again my fault - i misinterpreted the original request and edited

Answer (score 0):

With MS SQL-Server you can use [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) + [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT Count = Count(*),
       Date = (SELECT TOP 1 [date] 
               FROM   currentdatetable)
FROM   accountstable a 
WHERE  Datediff(dd, a.[date], (SELECT TOP 1 [date] 
                               FROM   currentdatetable)) > 90
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b408/10/0)

Answer (score -1):

You could optimize upper answer with select only bigger date:

select count(*) from accountstable at where at.date > (select TOP 1 dateadd(day, -90,date) from currentdatetable ORDER BY date DESC)